# data model for magazine store in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller, data-modeling

I want to create a rails 3.2.7 application for online magazine store.
I design quick data model for this application but I'm not sure it is good or bad!?
I have Magazine table for all magazines, I have Product table for all version of specific 
Magazine and I have Page table for all pages of specific Product.

`Magazine has_many :Product`

`Product has_many :Pages` and `belongs_to :Magazine`

`Page belong_to :product`

I create this app but it has problems!!
for example in routes.rb I use this code

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :products do
    resources :pages
  end
end
```

but it's not work true !!!? 
I must change my data model or it's good for these application?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to separate the difference between routes and models.  The embedded routes that you have created just alter the url that each model exists under.  It can be useful for keeping track of parameters that are useful for the page request.  You should make sure that you write migrations for all the relationships.  Reading up on the [relational associations in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) might be helpful.

But basically, you need to have migrations that add the id of the related item to it's associated field.  So you will end up adding a `product_id` field to your `magazines` table